# Extracting pattern from the nested list in R using regex

Tags: regex, r, lapply

I have following sorted list (lst) of time periods and I want to split the periods into specific dates and then extract maximum time period without altering order of the list.

```
$`1`
[1] "01.12.2015 - 21.12.2015"

$`2`
[1] "22.12.2015 - 05.01.2016"

$`3`
[1] "14.09.2015 - 12.10.2015" "29.09.2015 - 26.10.2015"
```

Therefore, after adjustment list should look like this:

```
$`1`
[1] "01.12.2015" "21.12.2015"

$`2`
[1] "22.12.2015"  "05.01.2016" 

$`3`
[1] "14.09.2015"  "12.10.2015" "29.09.2015"  "26.10.2015"
```

In order to do so, I began with splitting the list:

```
   lst_split <- str_split(lst, pattern = " - ")
```

which leads to the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] "01.12.2015" "21.12.2015"

[[2]]
[1] "22.12.2015" "05.01.2016"

[[3]]
[1] "c(\"14.09.2015"             "12.10.2015\", \"29.09.2015" "26.10.2015\")"
```

Then, I tried to extract the pattern:

```
lapply(lst_split, function(x) str_extract(pattern = c("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+"),x))
```

but my output is missing one date (29.09.2015)

```
[[1]]
[1] "01.12.2015" "21.12.2015"

[[2]]
[1] "22.12.2015" "05.01.2016"

[[3]]
[1] "14.09.2015" "12.10.2015" "26.10.2015"
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could make it work and maybe propose more efficient solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your missing date is due to `str_extract` - use `str_extract_all`

Comment: Not sure why you need `str_extract as you need to get the max dates.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you it works but results in multilevel lists not so easy to manipulate and I want to avoid it.

Comment: @akrun I am sorry if it was not clear I want to create maximum time range per list. Therefore, it is quite simple in list 1 and 2, because there is only one range but in 3 I would have to combine 14.09.2015 and 26.10.2015, in order to get max time range. Here, I just show you simple working example but of course there might be more than 100 periods per list.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and @akun thank you! Now I understand it by combining your comments is is enough to use `str_extract_all(lst, "\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+")` and disregard my next steps with `str_extract`.

Comment: Or even `> lst_split <- str_split(lst, pattern = " - ")
> l <- str_extract_all(lst_split, "\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+")
> j <- sapply(l,paste,collapse=";")
> k = str_extract_all(j, "[^;]+;[^;]+")
> unlist(k)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Use `strsplit`, flatten each component using `unlist`, convert the dates to `"Date"` class and then use `range` to get the maximum time span.  No packages are used.

```
> lapply(lst, function(x) range(as.Date(unlist(strsplit(x, " - ")), "%d.%m.%Y")))
$`1`
[1] "2015-12-01" "2015-12-21"

$`2`
[1] "2015-12-22" "2016-01-05"

$`3`
[1] "2015-09-14" "2015-10-26"
```

**2)** This variation using a magrittr pipeline also works:

```
library(magrittr)
lapply(lst, function(x) 
   x %>% 
     strsplit(" - ") %>% 
     unlist %>% 
     as.Date("%d.%m.%Y") %>% 
     range
)
```

**Note:** The input `lst` in reproducible form is:

```
lst <- structure(list(`1` = "01.12.2015 - 21.12.2015", `2` = "22.12.2015 - 05.01.2016", 
`3` = c("14.09.2015 - 12.10.2015", "29.09.2015 - 26.10.2015"
)), .Names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: Thank you @G. Grothendieck, your code does exactly what I am aiming to achieve in just one line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to comments of @WiktorStribiżew and @akrun it is enough to use `str_extract_all`.

In this example:

```
> str_extract_all(lst,"\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+")
[[1]]
[1] "01.12.2015" "21.12.2015"

[[2]]
[1] "22.12.2015" "05.01.2016"

[[3]]
[1] "14.09.2015" "12.10.2015" "29.09.2015" "26.10.2015"
```